# Get record between two dates in datatables jquery

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I am working on datatables in jquery,Right now i am fetching all users record successfully,But
I want to know that how can i add "from" and "to" datefilter with datatables so i can get data between specific dates
Here is my current code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#usetTable').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, there is no PHP code, there is no SQL code, even there is no what `DataTable()` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table-id').DataTable({      
    "language": {
        "search": "_INPUT_",
        "searchPlaceholder": "Search..."
    },
    "processing": true, 
    "serverSide": true, 
    "ajax": {
        "url": "URL",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": function ( data ) {
                data.start_date_filter = $('#start_date_filter').val();
                data.end_date_filter = $('#end_date_filter').val();                 
            },
        "dataSrc": function ( json ) {             
           return json.data;
       }
    },
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
        "targets": [ ], 
        "orderable": false, 
    },
    ],
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {          

     },
});
```